# Correct format for post request from axios to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I'm trying to use Axios (because it's light) for a post request to PHP. Here's my code for the post request:

```
var params = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://myurl.com',
  data: myData,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
}
axios(params).then(...).catch(...);
```

I've had mild success with the following `myData`:

```
var myData = {
  data: {
    lastRequest: '2017-10-19T17:09:10.943Z'
  },
  validationType: 'timestamp'
}
```

Bizarrely, though, in PHP, it turns up as the array key in $_POST:

```
// var_dump of $_POST
'{"data":{"lastRequest":"2017-10-19T17:09:10.943Z"},"validationType":"timestamp"}' => ''
```

So, although it's a bit strange, I can do something with it. However, I also want to send more complex data from a third-party API:

```
var myData = {
  data: {
    coord: {
      lon: -9.99,
      lat: 52.71
    },
    weather: [
      {
        id: 802,
        main: 'Clouds',
        description: 'scattered clouds',
        icon: '03d'
      }
    ],
    // etc
  },
  validationType: "weather"
}
```

This yields a really weird $_POST array in PHP:

```
// var_dump of $_POST
'{"data":{"coord":{"lon":-9_99,"lat":52_71},"weather":' => [
  '{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered clouds","icon":"03d"}' => ''
]
```

Not much I can do with that. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I know there are a few other similar StackOverflow questions, but I can't find any that have been answered satisfactorily. Would appreciate any help, thanks!

EDIT: Regarding `URLSearchParams`:

It seems to work OK with simple key-value pairs...

```
var myData = new URLSearchParams();
myData.append('lastRequest', '2017-10-19T17:09:10.943Z');
console.log(myData.toString()); // lastRequest=2017-10-19T17%3A09%3A10.943Z
```

...and arrays:

```
myData.append('myArray', ['foo', 'bar']);
console.log(myData.toString()); // myArray=foo%2Cbar (%2C is a comma)
```

But it doesn't handle objects, which is quite important in my case:

```
myData.append('myObject', {foo: 'bar'});
console.log(myData.toString()); // myObject=%5Bobject+Object%5D
```

Comment: Are you using axios from the browser or from node?

Comment: If you are using it from the browser, you need to try something like this `var myData= new URLSearchParams();myData.append('lastRequest', '2017-10-19T17:09:10.943Z');`...this step is needed when we try to send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format

Comment: @Hackerman Using the browser. Maybe there's another Content-Type that I should be using?

Comment: @Hackerman Thanks for reply. I can see how URLSearchParams might be useful for sending simple key/value pairs. Just wondering if it also works with more complex data (objects within arrays within objects, etc). Will check it out. Thx

Comment: It should works

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` shouldnt you be using `application/json`?

Comment: @prodigitalson Thanks for reply. Tried `application/json` and `application/json; charset=utf-8`. They both result in an empty `$_POST` array in PHP

Comment: did you try `$raw = file_get_contents('php://input');` then `$data = json_decode($raw);`? This would be with using `application/json` as the content-type.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing with Postman and jQuery, I've reached the conclusion that it's probably an issue with Axios. Following jQuery code (which seems to me to be equivalent to the above Axios code) does exactly what I want:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://myurl.com',
  data: myData,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

I was hoping to use a more lightweight library, but it's more important that it works!

EDIT: Came across [jQuery Builder](http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/), which can help to make jQuery more lightweight.